# Java MySQL query execution time

Tags: java, mysql, connection-pooling

I'm having a problem with mysql queries taking a little too long to execute.

```
private void sqlExecute(String sql, Map<Integer, Object> params) {

    try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection(); PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {

        if (params.size() > 0) {

            for (Integer key : params.keySet()) {

                statement.setObject(key, params.get(key));
            }
        }

        statement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've narrowed the problem down to the `executeUpdate()` line specifically. Everything else runs smoothly, but this particular line (and when I run `executeQuery()` as well) takes around 70ms to execute. This may not seem like an unreasonable amount of time, but currently this is a small test db table with under 100 rows. Columns are indexed, so a typical query is only looking at around 15 rows.

Ultimately however, we'll need to scan much larger tables with thousands of rows. Additionally, we're running numerous queries at a time (they can't really be batched because the results of each query are used for future queries), so all of those queries together are taking more like 7s.

Here's an example of a method for running a mysql query:

```
public void addRating(String db, int user_id, int item_id) {

    parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put(1, user_id);
    parameters.put(2, item_id);
    sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO " + db + " (user_id, item_id) VALUES (?, ?)";
    sqlExecute(sql, parameters);
}
```

A couple of things to note:

1. The column indexing is probably not the problem. When running the same mysql statements in our phpMyAdmin console, execution time is more like 0.3ms.
2. Also of note is that the execution time is consistently 70ms, regardless of the actual mysql statement.
3. I'm using connection pooling and wonder if this is possibly a source of the problem. In other tests, `dataSource.getConnection()` also takes about 70ms. I'm running this code locally.
4. The above example is for an `INSERT` using `executeUpdate()`, but the same problem happens for `SELECT` statements using `executeQuery()`.
5. I have tried using /dev/urandom per Oracle's [suggestion](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13209_01/wlcp/wlss30/configwlss/jvmrand.html), but this made no difference.

Comment: DO NOT ignore exceptions like that!!!

Comment: Looks like a roundtrip to the database takes 70 ms in your setup. It's the cost of communicating with the database server. Larger queries will not run much longer, unless of course the query itself is slow, or the amount of data is huge. Communication lag is always a problem, and you need to minimize the number of round-trips as much as possible. 70 ms does seem high. Have you tried running multiple statements on the same connection with autocommit set to false? You are talking to a database server on your *local* network, right?

Comment: @Andreas I know not to ignore exceptions, this is just slightly stripped down code until I get the query time reduced. It is good to know though that larger queries likely won't take longer. If that is the case, I can definitely reduce the time some by caching result data.

Comment: And I ran a few statements together with autocommit set to false, but still get the same time for each `executeUpdate()` or `executeQuery()` (70ms).  And the db is Google Cloud SQL.

Comment: Google Cloud. Yup, increased lag from having to cross the internet. If you need high roundtrip speed, the database needs to be on the local network. On remote network, you're stuck with the degraded performance you see. One way to improve overall performance, is to reduce the *number* of roundtrips, e.g. by pushing business logic to the server in the form of stored procedures. That way, multiple SQL statements can be executed on the server, and only the initial request and final result has to go cross the slow link.

Comment: @Andreas Excellent, good to know. The servlet that runs the queries will be deployed to Google App Engine in the end, so I assume the execution time will be reduced at that point? For now I've just been running the servlet locally for testing purposes.